# Inverted Triangle from String

Tags: c, string

I'm a bit confused on how to make an inverted triangle from user input so that the last character is removed each time and a space is added to the front of each row. So this is what I have now, it should be correct minus the spaces (which I can't seem to get to work for whatever reason). Should be a really simple for loop, but I just can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here's what it looks like when it's run now:

```
Enter a string: EXAMPLE

E X A M P L E
E X A M P L
E X A M P
E X A M
E X A
E X
E
```

---

and what I want it to look like:

```
Enter a string: EXAMPLE

E X A M P L E
 E X A M P L
  E X A M P
   E X A M
    E X A
     E X
      E
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    int c, k, length;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string);
    length = strlen(string);
    printf("\n");

    for(c=length; c>0; c--)
    {
        for(k=0; k<c; k++)
        {
            printf("%c ", string[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Apparently you want to **prepend** some spaces. How would you do this?

Comment: Clearly you will need to insert some spaces before the string. Where's the code to do that?

Comment: I'm asking how to do the loop for the spaces, I've tried a few different ways, but each time it gave me the wrong answer. Closest I got was spaces in the reverse order (so length # of spaces for the first row, length-1 for the second, etc.).

Comment: So show the attempt, and we will point out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just to add `length - c` spaces before printing each lines because the less characters you have to print, the more spaces you have to insert:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    int c, k, length;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string);
    length = strlen(string);
    printf("\n");

    for(c=length; c>0; c--)
    {
        //Add some spaces
        for(k=0; k < length - c ; k++)
        {
             printf(" ");
        }

        for(k=0; k<c; k++)
        {
            printf("%c ", string[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example with `SAMPLE STRING`:

```
Enter a string: SAMPLE STRING

S A M P L E   S T R I N G
 S A M P L E   S T R I N
  S A M P L E   S T R I
   S A M P L E   S T R
    S A M P L E   S T
     S A M P L E   S
      S A M P L E
       S A M P L E
        S A M P L
         S A M P
          S A M
           S A
            S
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert an increasing amount of spaces at every turn (i.e. `printf` space `k` times).